# Autogenerate Access Report Filename

Tags: database, ms-access

In Access 2007, I have a database that creates tasks for employees. The task information from the tables are input into a form and then sent from Outlook as a pdf. Each task has a unique task number.  Right now I am using the 'SendObject' macro to send the report (Task Assignment Report) as a pdf and the file is saved with that name.

Is there any way that the name for the pdf that gets saved and sent to Outlook to have the following generated format "Task Assignment FY13-###"  the ### being the task number that is from the table?

I am willing to separate from the macro and use VBA, just still not sure how to go about getting the name to autogenerate.

Answer (score 0):

You can output to, but you will need to code adding the attachment :

```
sName = "Task Assignment FY13-" & Me.TaskID
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "MyReport", acFormatPDF, sName
```

Or you can rename the report in code before each run.